# Embedding the Flowplayer in OS X

Tags: flash, flowplayer

For a site I'm using [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) and the Overlay tool from [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html), to show video. 
Within windows everything is fine in the main three browsers: IE7/8/9, Firefox and Chrome.

Within OS X (Snow leopard), the problems begin: A click in the video, anywhere, causes a reload. This is the case for the three browsers Safari, Firefox and Chrome (Not in Chrome 12.0.742.53 beta ???)

Giving the embeded player the property `wmode = 'opaque'` or `wmode = 'transparent'` results in the same situation on the windows platform, but only Firefox en Chrome browsers. Not in IE.

So `wmode` is really bugging me...

Does anyone have some good documentation on wmode ? I can't find anything suitable

See my problem at:

[Test page](http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/videotest.php)

[Test page without css](http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/videotest2.php)

[Standalone example page Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/demos/tools/overlay.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 <img id="CorporatePreviewImage1" src="http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.jpg" onMouseOver="javascript:this.src='http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1_kleur.jpg';"
                                        onmouseout="javascript:this.src='http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.jpg';" onClick="openVideoPlayer('http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.flv');" rel="#OverlayVideo" />
```

To:

```
 <a href="javascript: openVideoPlayer('http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.flv'); return false;" rel="#OverlayVideo">
         <img id="CorporatePreviewImage1" src="http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.jpg" onMouseOver="javascript:this.src='http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1_kleur.jpg';"
                                        onmouseout="javascript:this.src='http://www.jktv.nl/Andrew/movies/corporate/corporate_1.jpg';" /><br />
         </a>
```

Comment: Can anyone retest that on a mac?

Comment: Tnx for testing! What settings should I check?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know exactly what does that to JS on mac and I mean it does it on almost all browsers so it's a OS bug. A while ago I had big problems running my MooTools JS script on my mac until I reinstalled the whole OS. Than it all ran flawlessly. This might or might not be you case... What version of Snow Leopard are you running?

Comment: 10.6.7 also. Did you also tried to watch the movie in fullscreen? Or adjust the volume? No reload?

Comment: Oh, there's one other thing i have noticed. On my mac it tend's to cache the files even on hard refresh. Have you tried to manually empty the cache of you js scripts, so you have the latest version loaded from the site?

Comment: yup we did, but we can give it another try

Comment: Tnx! I'll give it a shot later today. The sources are not available to me right now.

Comment: Great! This did it! Only on Safari there is something strange: the first time it works flawlessy, after that the reloading appears again when clicking in the video.

Comment: What do you mean, the first time? The first time when browser is reset?

Comment: The first time the overlay is loaded I can see the video, click on fullscreen etc. When I close the overlay en reopen it again, the same behavior is back; reloading when clicking anywhere in the video

Comment: Try to destroy the flowplayer on close and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your main call in a jquery document.ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $openVideoPlayer('')
});
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. What's your idea behind this?

Comment: I read about someone else having a similar symptom. He fixed it like this. BTW I notice that the standalone example page does not have the symptom.